# How to mimic a web browser from Java using jSoup

Tags: java, url, html-parsing, jsoup

I am using a query like this in jSoup:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlString).timeout(1000).post();
```

It works for some sites, however:

- it doesn't work for Google search queries (e.g. urlString = "http://www.google.com/search?q=text") - I don't know why, how it is special
- result documents contain messages like "JavaScript should be turned on in your browser" which I would rather avoid
- there are probably more quirks, but I haven't tested it fully yet...

My question: could these problems be avoided if we could mimic a web browser more closely? What is the best way to do it?

What are the other differences that can be encountered between getting pages via web browser and via Java (URLConnection or jSoup)?

Comment: Jsoup is a HTML parser, not a HTML unit tester, nor is it intented as a GUI-less webbrowser. You may find [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) more interesting. Google blocks bots, check their policy file. Rather use their public search API.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this subject, and naively thought that I could achieve this with one (above) line of code, but then realized it doesn't work all the time as I want :) I guess I'll have a look at HtmlUnit...

Comment: Regarding Google, that is just the first site I encountered that doesn't respond to my url request at all, but I am afraid there are more sites which can't be accessed this way. I am still wondering why...

Comment: Either to prevent bandwidth waste by leeching and/or because there's already a more compact public web service API out to access the data you're looking for, or because it requires JavaScript enabled clients.

Comment: Thanks, but I was curious about which parameter(s) servers can detect in my above url request that help them decide not to respond at all. As far as I know, javascript capability is detected only client-side, when html is received, and also I think google search can work without JavaScript anyway.

Comment: The user agent header. Please keep in mind that user agent spoofing can be detected and result in IP bans. Read the `robots.txt` and policy file of the website in question which resources are open for leeching.

Comment: I won't be using this in loops or anything, but send occasional requests only, so I am not concerned about bot detection. Sorry for bloating comments section and taking your time, I'll figure this out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the problem with some sites not responding was actually that I was using post() instead of get(). With get() it works fine now!

It also probably helps to add userAgent to the query, for example:

```
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
```

In the meantime, I've also tested HtmlUnit for the same task, and it worked, but it seems like an overkill for the purpose to simply get an HTML file (for some kind of processing). It basically runs a whole invisible web browser in the background to do this task.

Comment: What about websites that require javascript and cookies?

Answer (score 2):

I will like to answer your question.
In Google , when you search , parameters are passed in URL , So it's a get request.
In this case , you should use .get() method.

While there are many websites , parameters are passed using post request.
Taking an example of a simple login page of all websites , username and password are passed using POST REQUEST , In addition to that there are many hidden fields inside that page which is also needed to be passed. 
If we missed that parmaters , it will result in a error.